# Proving basics of $(a+b)^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I need to prove this:

Consider the following inequality:

> $$a^2+ab+b^2 > 0$$

I know that $^2$ makes $a$ and $b$ positive numbers, so it always be $>0$, but i got stuck with the ab thing. I thought about $a^2+b^2+ab+ab=(a+b)^2,$ but no results... I also tried to think when the sum of $a^2+b^2$(not just a number) might bigger then $ab,$ but I'm having trouble using any of this to solve it.

Would be glad for any help!

p.s. sorry if i took it to the wrong section

SORRY to mention it! $b\neq0$ and $b,a$ are real numbers.

Comment: Hint: One possible direction might be to complete the square on $a^2+ab$.

Comment: If both $a,b\geq 0$ then this is true and likewise if both $a,b \leq 0$ this is true (if you remove the strict inequality), as all the terms are positive. So choose a to be positive and b to be negative without loss of generality and think about it from there.

Comment: SORRY to mention it! b=/=0 and b,a is Real nums

Answer (score 12):

$$a^2+ab+b^2=(a+\frac{1}{2}b)^2+\frac{3}{4}b^2$$

Comment: Drhab, plz explain to me why there's 3/4*b^2? I understand the (a+1/2*b)^2, it's the same as original, but can't figure it out about 3/4*b2.

Comment: @revolldxyz: You can multiply out the right-hand side and check why.  You can look up "completing the square" for more examples.

Comment: $\left(a+\frac{1}{2}b\right)^{2}$ is not the same as the original.
Worked out it becomes $a^{2}+ab+\frac{1}{4}b^{2}$ and that's why
$\frac{3}{4}b^{2}$is added to make it indeed $a^{2}+ab+b^{2}$

Comment: wow, man... that's genius! i definitely should look for 'completing the square' as Jonas mentioned! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Credit goes to @paw88789. His comment was there before my answer. You are very welcome.

Answer (score 3):

1. If $a>0$ and $b>0$ then obviously $a^2+b^2+ab>0$
2. If $a<0$ and $b<0$ same as $1$
3. If $a<0$ and $b>0$ assume $|a|>|b|$ thus $a^2-|a|b >0$ thus $a^2+ab+b^2>0$, if $|a|<|b|$ then $b^2-|a|b>0$ thus $a^2+b^2+ab>0$
4. If $a>0$ and $b<0$ similar to $4$

Answer (score 1):

$$a^2+ab+b^2=\frac1{b^2}\left[\left(\frac ab\right)^2+\frac ab+1\right]$$

Now make the change $x=a/b$ and study the sign of the polynomial $x^2+x+1$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint : $$ab\leq max\{a^2,b^2\}$$ then $(a+b)^2-ab>0$

Answer (score 0):

a^2-ab+b^2>0

Can be written

a^2+b^2>ab

*Case1:* a is positive b is negative, which means the statement is true same goes for the reverse, since a^2+b^2 will always be positive and ab will always be negative.

*Case2:* a and b are the same sign and one is greater than the other.

**a*a + b*b > ab**, if a is greater than b then **a*a>ab***, if b is greater than a then **bb > ab**

For example 3*3 > 3*2  and if b is larger 5*5>4*5, if they are different one must be greater than the other which means one of either a^2 or b^2 will be greater than ab, the highest possible outcome would be when a=b which is the next case.

*Case3:* a and b have the same sign and are the same number

**a*a + b*b > ab** can be rewritten as **n*n + n*n > n*n** which can be written as **2n^2>n^2**

Answer (score 0):

Focusing on the middle term, you can see that the quantity $a^2+ab+b^2$ lies $\frac 34$ of the way from $(a-b)^2$ to $(a+b)^2$, which are both non-negative, and which cannot both be zero, since $b\ne 0$.

Therefore it must be strictly positive.

Comment: Matt... can u explain it plz? I rly don't get it :/ what does it means it 3/4 of the way from (a-b)^2 to (a+b)^2? I feel like complete donkey

Comment: You probably know that $(a-b)^2=a^2-2ab+b^2$ and also that $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$. The only difference between these is the middle term, which is $-2ab$ in the first formula and $2ab$ in the second formula. You can see that $ab$ lies $\frac 34$ of the way from $-2ab$ to $2ab$. So $a^2+ab+b^2$ lies $\frac 34$ of the way from $(a-b)^2$ to $(a+b)^2$. The exact value $\frac 34$ doesn't matter -- it just matters that the quantity in the question, $a^2+ab+b^2$, lies _between_ those two squared values (or _equals both_ of them, if they are the same).